# div with text growing to the bottom, and then to top

Tags: css

I have a div with text under a div with an image. the normal case is that the text grows to the bottom, but when it reachs a defined height it should grow into/over the image area. could this be done with pure CSS?

regards

Comment: Please show your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using CSS.
You have to make the text div position: relative;

like this

```
.text{
position: relative;}
```

and the text inside the div must be position: absolute; bottom: 0;

like this

```
.text p{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;}
```